# Why won't my batch file run? Syntax Error

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt

## I keep getting a syntax error against the "C" in "C:\Users".

```
`#! python3

print('Hello world')`

#C:\Users\AK\MyPythonScripts>py.exe hello.bat
#  File "hello.bat", line 1
#    @py C:\User\AK\MyPythonSctipts\hello.py %*
#        ^
#SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried adding "\". I can't figure it out. Following along in "Automate the Boring Stuff." (Lesson 22)

```
#I keep getting a syntax error against the "C" in "C:\Users".

`#! python3

print('Hello world')`

#C:\Users\AK\MyPythonScripts>py.exe hello.bat
#  File "hello.bat", line 1
#    @py C:\User\AK\MyPythonSctipts\hello.py %*
#        ^
#SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expect to run the batch file and added a "@pause" feature, but the program won't execute since "C" is an invalid syntax.

Comment: Not able to find Lesson 22 in  "Automate the Boring Stuff". Not sure which version is it. As much I understand, I think this issue is with your windows command line execution.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. The lesson is on "Udemy.com". It's part of a lecture. The lecture is titled "Launching Python Programs from Outside Idle."

Answer (score 0):

May not the perfect answer you are looking for, but let me share in general essense how you run a python script in windows.

1. Open Command line:   Start menu -> Run  and type `cmd`
2. Type:   `C:\python27\python.exe C:\Users\Awesome\Desktop\Adel.py`

In your system, your python .exe location might a bit different or you could be using python3, but overall format is specify you python exe first followed by your script's full path (`<python.exe>  <python-script-full-path>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! My command prompt path wasn't set properly. I went to "My Computer" -> right-click -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings and changed my environment variable.